# use of no means

Tags: multiple-negation

what is the correct usage of "no means" , especially if used in double negative sentence. e.g I cannot by any no means allow you to do so. is this sentence correct? what if i use any means instead of no means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I can by no means allow..."

"I cannot by any means allow..."

both have the same meaning. A double negative is not correct.